# No inconsistencies due to closed timelike curves in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, causality, time-travel, closed-timelike-curve

Is there anything wrong with the following argument ruling out inconsistencies with closed timelike curves?

**Math**

A *solution* in the context of General Relativity is a pseudo-Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$ with metric $g$, and further matter fields $\psi$ on $M$, where in each spacetime point $P \in M$ the fields $g(P)$ and $\psi(P)$ are *single-valued*.

A closed timeline curve $C$ is a curve with points $P \in C$ such that $P(\tau^\prime) = P(\tau) \; \wedge \; \tau^\prime > \tau$; $\tau$ is the proper time along $C$.

This does not create any paradoxa.

**Storytelling**

This is the story that one can follow such a closed timeline curve and decide to commit an act that causes a paradox.

**Logical flaw**

Modelling such a paradox mathematically would mean that at certain points $P \in M$ the matter fields $\psi(P)$ would *not* be single-valued ("I do exist at $P(\tau)$ and I do not exist at $P(\tau^\prime) = P(\tau)$").

So $\psi(P)$ together with $(M, g)$ would $not$ be a solution.

Comment: An argument like that might be half of showing that closed timelike curves do cause inconsistencies. If you follow a curve from $P(\tau)$ to $P(\tau')$, you might arrive at a different state than when you left. You have argued that this would be an inconsistency.

Comment: No. I have argued that this is impossible b/c a different state would mean, different field configurations, which is excluded by the fact that field configurations must be single-valued.

Comment: Right. My point was that suppose you tried to construct a solution and you found that it was multi valued at $P(\tau) = P(\tau ')$. Do you throw it out and conclude no solution exists? Or do you accept an inconsistent solution? As Willo said, it takes more than your argument.

Comment: I have no multi-valued solution at hand which I want to rule out. I want to rule out storytelling which does not use any solution at all, so I think my argument is sufficient; it does not rely on any specific solution, just on the general properties of solutions: either i) single-valued => no paradox; or ii) multi-valued => not an allowed solution => no paradox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are models of general-relativity-plus-closed-timelike curves, e.g. Godel's.   Therefore the theory of general-relativity-plus-closed-timelike curves cannot be inconsistent.  This is the easy direction of Godel's completeness theorem, which says that a theory is consistent if and only if it has a model.   [So Godel's name appears twice in this paragraph, for two very different reasons.]

Your storytelling makes no sense, for reasons you have correctly identified.  But if your goal is to rule out the possibility of an inconsistency in general-relativity-plus-closed-timelike curves, there's no need to refute this kind of storytelling in the first place.  The existence of a model is all you need.

Comment: The existence of a model – like Goedel‘s – shows only that this specific model is consistent. There *is* this storytelling which I want to rule out, but you can’t do that based on models. There are no models including every detail like me, my father, the grandfather etc. b/c they are too difficult to construct.

Comment: @TomS:   To say that a specific model is consistent is like saying that a specific model is a vegetarian --- the concept simply doesn't apply.   **Theories**, not models, are or are not consistent.   One model is enough to prove the consistency of the theory.

Comment: 1) I want to rule out storytelling, so I don't understand how your argument applies. Suppose a very simple theory says that 
i) the geometry of the universe is $S^1 \times \mathbb{R} $, where the circle is the time-direction, 
ii) Galilei invariance shall apply, 
iii) solutions to field equations must be single-valued. 
Then I can construct functions *either* respecting periodicity in time, which results in valid solutions, *or* functions *not* respecting periodicity, i.e. which are multi-valued and therefore no valid solutions. 
What is wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: 2) Regarding consistency or inconsistency of the theory - again using $S^2 \times \mathbb{R}$: i) there multi-valued functions which I exclude by definition - OK
ii) and there are single-valued functions which are acceptable and prove that the theory has at least one solution - OK.  
I was not after this question (2), but ok, thanks for the input.